# widget into List<Widget> does not update into build method even if i call setState

Tags: flutter, dart

i have the following simple full code

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  List myListWidget = [];
  late bool isColorWhie = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        setState(() {
          myListWidget.add(
              Container(
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                color: isColorWhie?Colors.white:Colors.red,
              )
          );
        });
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              ...myListWidget,
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                   setState(() {
                     isColorWhie = !isColorWhie; // here never update 
                     log('done');
                   });
                  },
                  child: const Text('tab to Change color',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i tap on any point on screen to add Container into `myListWidget` thn call  `setState(() {});` to update ui.
everything fine now but when i change the `isColorWhie` to true it should change the color to white but it never update !

i am totally confused why it does not update ? And how could i handle with this ?

Comment: I think I didnt change anything, working on my snippet. are you trying to change created widget color or just new one?

Comment: i want change the color of the widget that i added

Comment: that are already contains on  `myListWidget`?

Comment: yes .. i need to update the state for anything i want that already added into myListWidget

Comment: like if i want to update any normal widget . but this time with those that already created into myListWidget

Comment: Does below post answer your post, Is it will be for container widget for your implementation?

Comment: Unfortunately he explained the reason but it is useless answer comparing if i need solution

Comment: It would be easier with StateManagement property

Comment: so do you think widgets that already created into myListWidget  would be updated if i implement them with StateManagement  ?

Comment: I think, But there might be easier option for this case, let me check

Comment: i really hope so !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For base color change, I am using a separate button, also switching the list value.
One thing variable does update the UI, you need to handle state inside the item(state-management property) or reinitialize the variable to get update state.

```dart
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  List<bool> myListWidgetState = [];
  bool isColorWhie = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(
          () {
            myListWidgetState.add(isColorWhie);
          },
        );
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              ...myListWidgetState.map(
                (e) {
                  return Container(
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    color: e ? Colors.white : Colors.red,
                  );
                },
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  myListWidgetState = myListWidgetState.map((e) => !e).toList();
                  setState(() {});

                  print(isColorWhie);
                },
                child: const Text(
                  'tab to Change color',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isColorWhie = !isColorWhie;
                  });

                  print(isColorWhie);
                },
                child: const Text(
                  'tab to Change base color',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank .. you really saved me from headache .. and yeaah by the way StateManagement doing great job in my case

Comment: Glad to help, also you can use method that will return list instead of list variable. But for project case, State-management is better

Answer (score 0):

Since you create a container as an object in GestureDetector and save it to your list, it will not change. It is now permanently saved (of course as long as you do not delete the element) as an entry in your list.

Your logic works exactly as you programmed it. For example, if you were to recompile the app and press the TextButton and then anywhere on your screen, a white container would also appear.

If you want to dynamically change the color of all containers at once, then you can do the following:

```
class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  int containerCounter = 0;
  late bool isColorWhie = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          containerCounter++;
        });
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 50,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: containerCounter,
                  itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 50,
                      color: isColorWhie ? Colors.white : Colors.red,
                    );
                  }),
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isColorWhie = !isColorWhie; // here never update
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    'tab to Change color',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Ozan Taskiran for explaining the reason . i do understand the reason now by you . but still looking for solution . thanks !

Comment: What is wrong with my solution? Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: sorry my bad .. but in my case i cannot use listView

Comment: i need to update widget that already created and added directly within   ...myListWidget,